# Convert my list of datetime objects to a month wise date frame segregation or directly plot it

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, plot, calendar

```
my_original_list = ['December 1, 2003', 'February 22, 2004', 'February 29, 2004', 'March 8, 2004', 'December 25, 2003']
```

```
I have extracted the above list from a .txt file and converted it into datetime using 

from datetime import datetime
new_list = []
for i in my_original_list:
    dates = datetime.strptime(i, '%B %d, %Y').date()
    new_list.append(dates)
print(new_list)
```

After which I have got a list like

new_list = [datetime.date(2003, 12, 1), datetime.date(2004, 2, 22), datetime.date(2004, 2, 29), datetime.date(2004, 3, 8), datetime.date(2003, 12, 25)]

Now I need this list to plot my graph on a monthly basis.. Like January - 2 items, February - 3 items, etc.
So will I need to convert this into a data frame or can I plot this directly.

Please guide me how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the month names for the dates inside `new_list` using `.strftime()`.
Then you can use `Counter` to get the count for each month that occurs inside the dictionary.
Counter sorts the items by their count, but you can later sort the dictionary differently so that it better represents the data you want to plot.
As for creating the plot, you can use the `matplotlib` library.

```
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


new_dict = Counter([d.strftime("%B") for d in new_list])

plt.bar(range(len(new_dict)), new_dict.values(), align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(new_dict)), new_dict.keys())
plt.yticks(range(1, max(new_dict.values()) + 1), range(1, max(new_dict.values()) + 1))

plt.show()
```

Here's a sample result (I added some extra data to see how it scales up):
[Sample result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Av0a.png)

I can't comment on your post due to low reputation, so update your post if my solution doesn't exactly fit your needs.

Comment: That worked. But this raises me another question. If we are converting it to a string why can't we do all these without converting it to a 'datetime' in the first place.

Comment: We absolutely could, it really depends on your needs. You can completely skip the datetime part and just display the month numbers as the x-axis labels or create a separate dictionary (or even a list) that maps month numbers to their names.